# How to use apply a custom drawable to RadioButton?

Tags: android

It looks like we can use the following in a RadioButton:

```
android:button="@drawable/myCustomStateBackground"
```

but that drawable only occupies the spot where the radio drawable would normally go. Ideally I want my entire button background to be stateful. So when pushed, I want the entire button to look like its stuck in the pressed state. To do that, I was hoping I could do something like:

```
android:button="null"
android:background="@drawable/myCustomStateBackground"
```

but then the background drawable doesn't know about push state, like the button attribute does. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Rather than changing the background, you're probably looking for the `android:button` attribute.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Give your radiobutton a custom style:

```
<style name="MyRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/custom_btn_radio</item>
</style>
```

**custom_btn_radio.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_pressed" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_pressed" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_selected" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
</selector>
```

Replace the drawables with your own.

Comment: Ah sorry - this will only modify the "button" drawable - I'd like to modify the background drawable - but also have its state behave like the "button" attribute - doesn't look like RadioButton supports that?

Comment: using this drawable once my radio button gets checked it's never get unchecked

Comment: @umerk44 That's the way a RadioButton works if it's not part of a group. If you need it to be unselectable you can use a CheckBox.

Comment: It helps to me only with additional settings `<style name="CustomRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:button">@drawable/ic_check_selector</item>
        <item name="android:buttonTint">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:buttonTintMode">multiply</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 45):

You should set `android:button="@null"` instead of `"null"`.

You were soo close!

Answer (score 44):

full solution here:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/oragne_toggle_btn"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/oragne_toggle_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/oragne_toggle_btn"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```

selector XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/orange_btn_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/orange_btn_unselected"    android:state_checked="false"/>

 </selector>
```

Comment: or you could use `android:button="@drawable/oragne_toggle_btn"`

Comment: Do not use background attribute use >android:button="@drawable/oragne_toggle_btn"

Comment: What about text color?

Comment: Old thread, I know... It looks like the above solutions  `android:button="@drawable/oragne_toggle_btn"` or `android:button="@null"` and `android:background="@drawable/oragne_toggle_btn"` are not working when using an API < API 21.  
Any alternatives for API 18 that  makes it possible to replace the default radiobutton image with your own?

Answer (score 12):

if you want to change the only icon of radio button then you can only add `android:button="@drawable/ic_launcher"` to your radio button and for making sensitive on click then you have to use the selector

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_what_you_want_on_select_state" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_what_you_want_on_un_select_state"    android:state_checked="false"/>


 </selector>
```

and set to your radio `android:background="@drawable/name_of_selector"`

Comment: If m using 
android:button="@null"
android:background="@drawable/myCustomStateBackground"
for a radio button which is located in navigation drawer menu. It is not working properly. Some times background images are visible but sometimes not. Please help regarding same.

Answer (score 0):

In programmatically, add the background image

minSdkVersion 16

```
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(this);
radioButton.setBackground(R.drawable.account_background);
rg.addView(radioButton);
```