# Can not create Custom Radio Button

Tags: android

I try to create custom radio button but the result is not good, with this code:
custom_radio.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/radio_off"/>

</selector>
```

and main.xml

```
<RadioGroup
                    android:id="@+id/radioSex"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/male"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="@string/male"
                        android:background="@xml/custom_radio"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/female"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/female"
                        android:background="@xml/custom_radio"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />
                </RadioGroup>
```

the result is this:
[image]

How to solve this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432553/radiobutton-how-to-use-a-custom-drawable can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
 android:button="@null"
```

to your `RadioButton`. Also drawable like xml should be placed inside the `drawable` folder

Comment: now my text is on button. and height and width are small. how to fix it ?

Comment: You can try to  add some padding