# How to Change Color of Radio Button in android?

Tags: android

I want to know how to change color of circle and border of radio button in android.please help me i trying this for two days.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/52802572/4797289

Answer (score 5):

More simple, just set the buttonTint color: (only works on api level 21 or above)

```
<RadioButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/radio"
android:checked="true"
     android:buttonTint="@color/your_color"/>
```

in your values/colors.xml put your color in this case a reddish one:

```
<color name="your_color">#e75748</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `drawable` to your `RadioButton` to change the color and border or any other part of it.

You can find more info here: [RadioButton - how to use a custom drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432553/radiobutton-how-to-use-a-custom-drawable)

You can use the `tint` feature, but this won't work in older devices. Choose this if you are not supporting < API 21.