# RadioButton with vector drawables

Tags: java, android, xml, radio-button, vector-graphics

I'm trying to make gender switcher using RadioButtons. Now it looks like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E9VR.png).

I use vector drawables as icons. I want to make it `@color:colorAccent` and change its background to a white circle, when button is pressed. How would be better to do it?

**layout.xml**

```
<RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_btn_radio"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_btn_radio"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RadioGroup>
```

**custom_btn_radio.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/human_male"/>
<item android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/human_male"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:tint="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`<selector>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) to select different drawables for different states.

Then for the color, as you are using a vector drawable, you can animate properties of it: [`AnimVector`](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#AnimVector) So you could be able to animate the color, even if it's a zero duration animation (in theory, it's not something I have done).

Comment: I'm using a selector now (XML is provided in the question), but it doesn't work, buttons always look like unchecked.

Comment: You must now use `android:button="@drawable/custom_btn_radio"/>` If that's what you call it, probably should mention `male` in the name.

Comment: I'm already using `android:button="@drawable/custom_btn_radio"/>`, just forgot to update the code in question when added selector

Comment: If you still see nothing, why don't you try checked->male unchecked->female. If that works, then it's simply that you cannot use background or tint.

Comment: Odd, few things to try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432553/radiobutton-how-to-use-a-custom-drawable

Comment: Yep, now that works, but only for icon. Is it possible to make white background for checked radiobutton in some way?

Comment: You wanted a circle background, I would consider a LayerList to combine a circle [Shape Drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) with yours: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList