# Change checked radio button color

Tags: android, xml, android-styles, android-studio-2.3

I want to change checked `RadioButton` color. But I don't know the way to change it. Below there are some code and picture represented.

```
<RadioButton
  android:id="@+id/type_cambodia"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="30dp"
  android:button="@null"
  android:drawablePadding="20dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_margin"
  android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"
  android:text="@string/type_goal_khmer_kh"/>
```

[image: Picture of UI showing here ->]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design your own custom drawable.

```
<style name="MyRadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/custom_btn_radio</item>
</style>
```

**custom_drawable_for_radio_button.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_pressed" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_pressed" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_selected" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
</selector>
```

In the selector items you can assign a custom "ON" drawable with a different color. Then use this custom drawable for you radio button instead of the default one.

[RadioButton - how to use a custom drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12432553/radiobutton-how-to-use-a-custom-drawable)