# Android Radio button selector

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on a custom radio button, when adding custom drawables to the selector assigned to the button it is not showing but it is working when adding images to the selector.

Comment: Did you try the https://stackoverflow.com/a/12432722/4779042 solution ? Or did you look up the other solutions on the stackoverflow ?

Comment: yes, same issue

Comment: please add codes to your question